# Erreur "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdbc, driver

I start a project with Java (8, SDK 21.0.2) on IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.1.
MMy database is on PostgreSql (16).
I created the class + method below, in order to test my database connexion :

```
import java.sql.*;


public class Connect {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            Connection connection = null;
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:PORT/DB", "USER", "PASSWORD");
            System.out.println("OK ! :)");
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("KO ! :(");
        }
    }
}
```

I download the driver postgresql-42.7.3.jar, which I put in a repository "lib" within my project.
On IntelliJ, I went in File > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies > I added postgresql-42.7.3.jar. The way associated is exactly the same than the repository "lib" in my project.
But when I write the command "java Connect.java", I got the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver".
Have I missed something in the manual installation of the driver ? (I don't use Gradle or Maven)
Thanks for your answers !

- I installed the drive as dependency of my project
- I installed the plugin DB Navigator on Intellij > I provided the informations about my database > the connexion test is successfull
- I wrote the absolute way of my driver in my environment variables

Comment: The `Class.forName()` line hasn't been needed since 2006. Clearly you have not deployed the driver .jar file correctly. Many duplicates here, all saying the same thing.

Comment: The error means that the driver is not on your runtime classpath. The fact the DB Navigator plugin can connect means nothing in this context: that is within IntelliJ, which uses a different classpath than your application. If you run with `java Connect.java`, then you don't have **any** library on the classpath other than Java's built-in classes and the content of `Connect.java`. At minimum you should use `java -cp postgresql.jar Connect.java`, but know that running Java source files like that is only for basic uses cases.